# Problem with compare value with its aggregate function within the same table

Tags: database-design, sqlite

[image]

I need to find the list of `customer_id` for customer who have spent more than the average customer.

This is the the query I use to generate table above:

```
SELECT customer_id, sum(Total) AS customer_total
FROM (SELECT T.order_id, customer_id, Total
              FROM (SELECT order_id, SUM(quantity * B.price) AS Total
                    FROM ORDERITEM AS O, BOOK AS B
                    WHERE B.b_id = O.bid
                    GROUP BY O.order_id) AS A JOIN "TRANSACTION" AS T
                          ON A.order_id = T.order_id)
GROUP BY customer_id
ORDER BY customer_total DESC
```

How can I start from here to find the list of customers who have spent more than the average customer? And also how to give the limit of digits for double? Thanks in advance!

Below is the query I tried, but it returns empty. And I am sure the correct result is not empty.

[image]

Comment: I assume the "average customer" is the customer who has **MEDIAN** total cost. How to find median?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a [common table expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html):

```
WITH CustTotals AS ( ... your query above ...)
SELECT *
FROM CustTotals
WHERE customer_total > (SELECT AVG(customer_total)
                        FROM CustTotals);
```

Comment: OMG, that was brilliant ! It works perfect, thank you so much!

Comment: Nice! +1 - I forgot that SQLite has CTEs.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this (note: untested).

```
SELECT customer_id, cust_tot, cust_avg FROM
(
  SELECT customer_id, ROUND(customer_total, 2) AS cust_tot, AVG(customer_total) AS cust_avg
  FROM
  (
-- This is your query yq
    SELECT customer_id, sum(Total) AS customer_total
    FROM 
    (
      SELECT T.order_id, customer_id, Total
      FROM 
      (
        SELECT order_id, SUM(quantity * B.price) AS Total
        FROM ORDERITEM AS O, BOOK AS B
        WHERE B.b_id = O.bid
        GROUP BY O.order_id) AS A 
          JOIN 
          ORDER_TRANSACTION AS T
          ON A.order_id = T.order_id
        )
      GROUP BY customer_id
      ORDER BY customer_total DESC  -- yq ends
    ) AS TAB
  ) AS TAB2
WHERE TAB2.cust_tot > TAB2.cust_avg
```

Comment: I am kind of newbie with database, I didn't realize that "TRANSACTION" is a keyword. The compiler return an error says _misuse of aggregate function AVG()_ , I suppose that aggregate function only allowed in SELECT?

Comment: I have edited my answer. That'll teach me to answer here when it's late and I've no machine for testing! Again: not tested.

Comment: Just now I try the same thing, to get total spend and average spend at same time, then compare it, but the result is empty. It seems it cannot compare the same attribute within the same table?